# What does (int (*)()) mean in a function call

Tags: c

Like the title says, I want to know what "*(int (*)())*" in a C-define-function-call means?

As example, it looks similar to this:

```
#define Bla(x)    (Char *) read((char *(*)()) Blub, (char **) x)
```

or this

```
#define XXX(nx, id)     PEM_ASN1_write_bio((int (*)()) id, (char *) nx)
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The casts the argument to a pointer to a function that returns `char *` and takes zero or more arguments. The second function returns `int`.

You can use a program (and website, now) called "[cdecl](http://www.cdecl.org/)" to help with these, it says:

- `(char *(*)())`: cast unknown_name into pointer to function returning pointer to char
- `(int (*)())`: cast unknown_name into pointer to function returning int

Comment: In fact, cdecl cannot parse these

Comment: @JS Bangs: I agree! Just to be clear, I have no affiliation with it at all, just found it when trying to answer this question. :)

Comment: cdecl also converts english like sentences into C declaration . e.g. 'declare p as pointer to integer' will give you 'int *p ' as output.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way of deciphering complex C expressions is to start with the innermost expression, then in an anti-clockwise pattern move on to the next.
(int (*)())

1. (*) A Pointer, anti-clockwise motion hits on (, then move on again to hit on )
2. (*)() A pointer to function, move on to (, then move on again to )
3. int (*)() A pointer to a function returning int, move on to int, then move on to hit on )
4. (int (*)()) finally move on to (, and there you have it,

A pointer to a function returning int, since it is wrapped in the outer () is because of the macro.

Hope this helps,
Best regards,
Tom

Answer (score 1):

`(int (*)())` is a typecast operator, which is to say you ask the compiler to behave
as if the expression on its right were of type `int (*)()`. As others have indicated,
the type in question means "a pointer to a function accepting any arguments,
and returning an `int`".

To understand the type itself, you first need to understand the weird way in which
variables are declared in C: in most languages, the syntax for variable declarations
is constructed from the syntax for type specifications, but in C, in a way,
it's the other way around.

If you were to declare a variable containing a pointer to such a function, you would write:

```
int (*fp)();
```

meaning that an expression resembling `(*fp)()` would be of type `int`: "take `fp`,
dereference it, call that with any arguments and you will get an `int`".

Now, in order to obtain a typecast operator for the type of `fp` in the above declaration, lose the identifier and add parentheses around: you get `(int (*)())`.

Answer (score 0):

It means that the first argument of `read`, named `Blub` is a pointer to a function that returns a `char *` and receives no arguments.

Answer (score 0):

First one says that read takes "a function pointer that returns a char pointer" as first argument and "pointer to a char pointer" as second argument. If you want to do Bla, just write Bla(x), I ll handle de read part!

Second one says that, first parameter to PEM_ASN1_write_bio must be "a function pointer returning an int". And the second argument is "a pointer to a char". And you can use XXX(a,b) instead of PEM_ASN1_write_bio(b,a), thats all